# 複数の外部連携ログインを実装する時のデータベーステーブル設計について

Tags: mysql, データベース設計

やりたいこと
メールアドレスでもXアカウント経由でもBlueskyアカウント経由からでもログインできるよう実装したい

悩んでいる点
userテーブルを 1 つにするか、3 つにするか

それぞれ必要なカラム内容が異なるので、当初は下記 3 テーブルを作成しようと思ったのですが、
・メールアドレス用のuser_mテーブル
・Xアカウント用のuser_xテーブル
・Blueskyアカウント用のuser_bテーブル

全データ取得する際、結合が複雑になるのではないか、と思い悩んでいます。

下記いずれが適切だと思われますか？
それぞれのメリットデメリットを知りたい。

案A.下記 3 テーブルを作成
・メールアドレス用のuser_mテーブル
・Xアカウント用のuser_xテーブル
・Blueskyアカウント用のuser_bテーブル

案B.下記 1 テーブルを作成
・「メールアドレス」「X」「Bluesky」全てで必要なカラムを含むuserテーブル
・typeカラムを作成して、そこに「メールアドレス」か「X」か「Bluesky」いずれかであることを判定できる値を格納

Comment: 構成以前に、認証システムを自作するのは無謀です。環境に合わせて既製のメジャーなライブラリを探してきて使いましょう。

Comment: 自ずとデータベースの構成もそちらに引っ張られます

Answer (score 4, accepted):

そもそもの話として、ユーザーはメールアドレス、Xアカウント経由、Blueskyアカウント経由のいずれか一つしか設定できないのでしょうか？例えば、スタック・オーバーフロー(厳密にはStackExchange)ではメールアドレスとパスワードでのログインの他にGoogle、GitHub、Facebookでもログインできますが、最初の登録後に、他のログインも追加できます。通常、別のサービスのアカウントでログインできるという仕組みを提供している場合、追加で設定できたり、解除できたりする場合が多いです。

もし、メールアドレスでユーザー登録後にXアカウントでのログインを追加できるようにする場合、一人のユーザーにメールアドレス・パスワードとXアカウントの両方が必要になります。そのような状態で案Aを選んだ場合、user_mとuser_xに同じユーザーとして扱うべき情報が重複して入れる必要があるでしょう。単純にそのユーザーの表示名を取ろうとするだけで、二つのテーブルから同じような情報が来ることになり、どちらを正ににすればいいのかよくわからないことになります。今度は表示名を更新しようにも二つのテーブルを更新する必要があり、片方の更新失敗などの不整合が起きた場合も想定すると処理が非常に複雑になります。ということで、案Aは止めた方がいいでしょう。

では、案Bで良いのかというと、そのユーザーとしてログインできるXアカウントを複数持たせたいとなったらどうなるでしょうか？userテーブルにはXアカウントの情報を複数載せるために初めから枠を複数とかしても、二つじゃ足りないとか、どんどん増えていってテーブルが酷いことになります。よって、案Bも要件によっては破綻します。

ということで、単純なメールアドレス・パスワード以外のログインを設けるというのであれば、ユーザー情報と認証情報のテーブルを分けたほうがいいと思われます。ユーザーに関する情報はuserテーブルにおいて、認証処理以外はこのテーブルだけで十分になります。認証情報テーブルはサービスによって情報が異なる可能性があるのでサービス毎に分けた方が良いかもしれません(OAuthを使用しているサービスであれば同じ情報でまとめられるかもしれない)。下記のような感じです。

- user: id:int, name:str, ...
- auth_m: id:int, user_id:int, email:string, encrypted_password:string, locked:bool, ...
- auth_x: id:int, user_id:int, account:string, ...
- athu_b: id:int, user_id:int, account:string, provider:string, ...

idはプライマリキー、user_idはuserテーブルのidに関する外部キーです。

メールアドレス・パあスワードの組合せは一つだけしか持たせないという単純な運用ならuserに入れても良いかもしれません。この方法の利点は、別のサービスを後から増やしたり、逆に廃止することができると言うことです。その他にも、2要素認証やパスキーとか認証の方法が追加されるときに、userテーブルに触れなくても良いというのは、メリットがあるかとも思います。

Comment: 一人が複数サービスを併用するケースや、一人が同じサービスで複数アカウントを併用するケースは想定していませんでしたが、どう対応するか予め決めておくべきだと思いました。「ユーザー情報と認証情報のテーブルを分けたほうがいい」アドバイスありがとうございました。質問時点では思いつきませんでしたが、「なるほど」と思いました

Answer (score 3):

案A.のメリット
・そのアカウント固有の情報（user_mテーブルならメールアドレス）も格納できる。

案A.のデメリット
・全データ取得する際、結合が複雑になる
・３テーブル合わせて、ユニークなIDを確保する必要がある

案B.のメリット、デメリットは、案A.の反対になります。

小規模システムでしたら、案Bで、問題ないのではないでしょうか。
大規模システムでしたら、ログインの認証以外に、蓄積したアカウント情報が
どのように利用される可能性があるか検討/確認したほうが良いです。